# Current transformer (CT) and potential transformer (PT) grounding

Tags: high-voltage, current-transformer

There is several documents say that for three-phase instrument transformers (CT,PT), there should be only one grounding point. With this argument, can I short the the secondary sides of current transformer and voltage transformer together on a bus-bar and then ground this bus-bar to create a single grounding point?

In fact, these CT and PT have already been installed at the substation and they are grounded, just not at the same point. My company will install a meter that uses their outputs. This meter have its CT and PT neutral wires connected on the circuit board and as mentioned, these neutral wires are grounded at their own points. So technically, the grounds of the said CT & PT are connected together. I'm asking if there is any potential danger to this.

Note that these CT and PT are used in measurement of High Voltage substation (110 kV).

Circuit to illustrate the idea:
[image]

Comment: What do the data sheets for the CT and PT recommend?

Comment: The datasheet for CT state that there should be only one single grounding point (for CT) and the same goes for the PT datasheet. I just wonder if these two grounding points could be connected together.

Comment: Electrically that makes sense, I don't know if there are any regulations governing that.

Comment: Do the data sheets explicitly say that the outputs MUST be grounded?

Comment: I forgot to mention that these are 3-phase transformers. In fact, these CT and PT have already been installed at the substation and they are grounded, just not at the same point. My company will install a meter that uses their outputs. This meter have its CT and PT neutral wires connected on the circuit board and as mentioned, these neutral wires are grounded at their own points. So technically, the grounds of the said CT & PT are connected together. I'm asking if there is any potential danger to this.

Comment: @Andyaka even if they don't for comfort i'd want it. 13.8KV ! you'd likely feel the leakage current through capacitance of the transformer through the glass of the meter.

Comment: @Hacle you should edit that into the question.

Comment: @Jasen, Done! What would happen when there is a ground fault and the outputs of these CT & PT are not balanced anymore? Would there be a disturbance on the neutral wire this disturbance would travel back and forth between the CT and PT? By the way, that 13.8 kV is just for illustration, it's actually is 110 kV.

Comment: @Jasen sounds reasonable for the PT but the data sheet for the CT might imply that another form of isolation might be required before connections to ground are made. Caution is called for etc..

Comment: If it promises isolation it should be safe to ground the secondary  the CT will have thick isulation on the main wire  so it should be inherently safe.  the PT has fuses (probably very expensive fuses) which will blow if the isolation fails and the secondary is grounded.

Answer (score 1):

The CT and PT secondary are grounded following the high voltage standards on the high voltage side of the installation. This area inaccessible by uncertified personnel, this grounding may not be removed.

> With this argument, can I short the the secondary sides of current transformer and voltage transformer together on a bus-bar and then ground this bus-bar to create a single grounding point?

You cannot, since you would make a ground loop.
If your meter requires this, you must add additional isolation transformers.

Answer (score 0):

so far as I can see.

The grounding of those windings must be at their neutrals
  else connecting the meter could cause a short-circuit

The two separate ground points must be bonded together
  else external fault currents could flow through the meter